# My Navigation bar and Alert title and Bottom Alert title became white in whole project

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, alert

My Navigation bar and Alert title and Bottom Alert title became white in whole project. I found answers only which are only perform on individual alerts but not as Global.

[image]

[image: 2]

```
  func inliseAlert(_ imageSelection:Int,_ VC:UIViewController ,_ success:@escaping ImageSelectionCompletion) {
//Change color of selection overlay to white
    viewController = VC
    numberOfImage = imageSelection
    self.success = success
    let imageSourceAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Choose Image", message: "", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.actionSheet)
   
    let camera = UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default) { [weak self](action: UIAlertAction) in
                   // Code to unfollow
                   DispatchQueue.main.async {
                       self?.openCamera()
                   }
               }
   
           let gallery = UIAlertAction(title: "Gallery", style: .default) {[weak self] (action: UIAlertAction) in
               // Code to unfollow
            guard let self = self else {return }
               DispatchQueue.main.async {
                   self.openGallery()
               }
           }
   
   
           let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .destructive, handler: nil)
           imageSourceAlert.addAction(camera)
           imageSourceAlert.addAction(gallery)
           imageSourceAlert.addAction(cancelAction)
   
         //  if let topController = UIApplication.getTopViewController() {
               viewController?.present(imageSourceAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
          // }
}
```

Comment: can you show your tried code

Comment: But this is only alert code, I have an issue in all alerts and navigation titles and buttons titles.

Comment: Search your code for .appearance() and check if some .appearance().[some property] has changed recently

Comment: I searched . appearance() in whole project, I only got IQKeyboard manager,FS Calendar files,Other than this I don't have any other code.@ArikSegal,and also the code for calendar is not in this class also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats some strange behavior...
From the screen shots you posted it looks like you were running on the simulator, I would make sure and check the behavior on a device just to rule out any strangeness.

Assuming the behavior persists on a device:

The first thing I notice is the comment in your code that says:

```
//Change color of selection overlay to white
```

I would look closely at what's that is referring to and what's happening in that process.

Such as the comment appears just before:

```
viewController = VC // I think the tintColor of viewController is causing this unwanted behavior
```

and then when you present the alert you are calling:

```
 //  if let topController = UIApplication.getTopViewController() {
               viewController?.present(imageSourceAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
          // }
```

Are viewController and TopViewController the same??
if not I think I would try:

```
 if let topController = UIApplication.getTopViewController() {
            topController.present(imageSourceAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
```

Also check the tintColor on the presenting ViewController try changing it before presenting the alert.

See if the behavior changes.

If it doesn't:

I would be looking at uses of `tintColor` in your code and storyboards.
Also maybe look for uses of `appearance()` in your code.

I suggest that because the only way to change that textColor globally I can think of (without use of an extension) would be something like

```
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.tintColor = .white
```

or

```
UILabel.appearance().textColor = .white
```

For that matter I would look to see if `UIAlertController` or `UIViewController` had any extensions in the project and if they do take a close look to what's happening there.

Also as ABV suggested look for and examine any use of `UIColor` especially `.white` or `.clear`.

If **ALL** else fails and you can't find the cause maybe you can use the above code/suggestions to reverse the effect, however I **strongly** suggest finding and correcting the root cause rather than adding more workarounds to fix the issue.

Without access to the project it is really a guessing game.

Comment: This was an issue.
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.tintColor = .white
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t have enough reputation to post in the comment section, but I would suggest you look for anywhere .white is written. Specially in ur appdelegate.